# Applications menu page indicator dots overlap the right-hand side dock

Tags: display, dock, appearance

when i dock the favorite icons bar to the right-hand side of the screen (just my preference), it will awkwardly cover the page indicator "dots" for the Show Applications menu which stay on the same right-hand side. is there a clean way to relocate those "dots" to the left-hand side or somewhere else instead to avoid overlapping?

Comment: IMHO Raise a bug with Ubuntu Dock Developers or with Ubuntu developers.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Dock is actually based on the Gnome Shell extension Dash to Dock. The issue you experience can only be solved by changing the workings of the extension through the programming code. So your best bet is to raise an issue to the developers of the Dash to Dock extension, if this has not already be done.

Issues are [filed here](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues). I did not find a similar issue reported on first look. This may be due to relatively few people placing the dock to the right, and even fewer of these people extensively using the dots for navigation through the applications. It is certainly worthwhile filing this, although solving this may not be trivial for the developers, as they would need to interfere with how the application grid is drawn.